# Using if inside of fold

Tags: if-statement, rust, fold

I need to count the length of a vector of `(bool, i32)` where if the `bool` is true I increment count. I'm using fold to do this:

```
fn main() {
    let domain = [(true, 1), (false, 2), (true, 3)];
    let dom_count = domain.iter()
        .fold(0, |count, &(exists, _)| if exists {count + 1});
    println!("dom_count: {}", dom_count);
}
```

The compiler complained saying:

```
.fold(0, |count, &(exists, _)| if exists {count + 1})
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found integral variable
```

So I added a `;` and got this:

```
.fold(0, |count, &(exists, _)| if exists {count + 1;})
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected integral variable, found ()
```

How do you correctly use an `if` statement inside of `fold`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What value are you attempting to use **when the `if` condition is `false`**?

That's what the compiler is telling you first. Because there's no `else` clause, the return type of the missing clause must be `()`. And since both the true and false branches of the `if` must have the same type, the true branch must return `()`. However, your true branch is trying to return a number.

By adding the `;`, you made it so that both branches of the `if` returned `()`, which then failed because your `fold` is *supposed* to return an integer.

One solution is to return a value in the `else` clause:

```
fn main() {
    let domain = [(true, 1), (false, 2), (true, 3)];

    let dom_count = domain.iter()
        .fold(0, |count, &(exists, _)| {
            if exists {
                count + 1
            } else {
                count
            }
        });

    println!("dom_count: {}", dom_count);
}
```

Or

```
fn main() {
    let domain = [(true, 1), (false, 2), (true, 3)];

    let dom_count = domain.iter()
        .fold(0, |count, &(exists, _)| {
            count + if exists {
                1
            } else {
                0
            }
        });

    println!("dom_count: {}", dom_count);
}
```

It's much more idiomatic to use `filter`:

```
fn main() {
    let domain = [(true, 1), (false, 2), (true, 3)];

    let dom_count = domain.iter()
        .filter(|&&(exists, _)| exists)
        .fold(0, |count, _| count + 1);

    println!("dom_count: {}", dom_count);
}
```

And the act of counting the the number of items is already handled by `Iterator::count`:

```
fn main() {
    let domain = [(true, 1), (false, 2), (true, 3)];

    let dom_count = domain.iter().filter(|&&(exists, _)| exists).count();

    println!("dom_count: {}", dom_count);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea that if-statements behaved like that. Also I apologize about the lack of MCVE, I cleaned it up. On a related note, why does Rust allow single line if statements to lack `;` if they are not returning a value? For instance it `count` is a variable why would this compile: `if true {count = 1}`? Shouldn't you be required to add a semi-colon: `if true {count = 1;}`?

Comment: @HiDefender *if they are not returning a value* — they **do** return a value - the value `()` of the type `()`. This is the empty tuple, sometimes called the "unit type".